# How to fit the header width unique across all the title card.?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to add the bootstrap card to my page. What happened is when the text is dynamic and larger than the card head, title is collapsed. I am looking for a way to fit the head same height across all the card so the next content align unique.

```
<div class="card-group">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">This card has supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="..." alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-block">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title Card title Card title Card title Card title Card title Card title Card title </h4>
      <p class="card-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This card has even longer content than the first to show that equal height action.</p>
      <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you want to show full title? If not so...you can truncate the rest to keep all cards' title of same size... try adding this class along with card-title  .fix{width: 250px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;}

Comment: No. Just want to make sure the below content horizantal start point is same on all card.

Comment: basically looking for auto adjust height in all card.

Comment: https://codepen.io/imohkay/pen/gpard

Comment: found this one as useful